# Placing separate directions API key in a request

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I already have an API key that I use for the google maps Javascript API.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&sensor=true"></script>
```

However, I got a new key for the directions API, since I want to request directions with more than 8 waypoints. Now I have the following issues.

1) Do we need separate API keys for directions API and the javascript API?

2) If we do, where do  put the new directions API key? Do I just reference it like an external script as above? if so, what would be the syntax?

3) Can we use more than 8 waypoints with a free API key? or do we need a work API?

Comment: Where did you get the "new key" from?

Comment: From the new key section of directions api. but I think it is the same api key. i was mistaken. thanks for theexplaination below.

Comment: I think the way google has worded their waypoints quota is misleading. It says "MAX_WAYPOINTS_EXCEEDED indicates that too many waypoints were provided in the request. The maximum allowed number of waypoints is 23, plus the origin and destination. (If the request does not include an API key, the maximum allowed number of waypoints is 8. Google Maps API for Work customers may submit requests with up to 23 waypoints.)"

It gives you the idea that if you include an API key, it will allow you 23 waypoints, when in reality they give it only for work APIs. That is why I mistook this.

Comment: Where is that quote from?  The one I see in the documentation for [DirectionsStatus](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsStatus) seems clear enough to me: `AX_WAYPOINTS_EXCEEDED - Too many DirectionsWaypoints were provided in the DirectionsRequest. The total allowed waypoints is 8, plus the origin and destination. Maps API for Work customers are allowed 23 waypoints, plus the origin, and destination.`

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro Go to the section Status codes.

Comment: Ah, that is the webservice, That certainly isn't as clear.

Comment: Created an issue in the issue tracker [Issue 8886: Bug: Directions API description of MAX_WAYPOINTS_EXCEEDED is not clear](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8886)

Comment: That would be very helpful. Does this mean the question is still too broad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only include one key in the load of the API, if you have one with more quota, you should use that, but it is probably a Google Maps for Work key, which is included differently (and comes with support directly from Google). You can not include more than 8 waypoints in a single request to the free API (although you can chain multiple requests together).

This has changed.  [Announced 11/10/2015](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.es/2015/11/predicting-future-with-google-maps-apis.html):

> We’re also making all traffic features in Directions API and Distance Matrix API available under our Standard Plan (2500 requests/day for free, with pay-as-you-go pricing for extra requests), and increasing the waypoint limit in Directions API for these developers from 8 to 23 waypoints. (Traffic features and higher waypoint limits in the JavaScript Maps API are available to Google Maps for Work customers for now.)

**23 waypoints are now available with the free API also.**